# shortcut for system.out.println in sublime text 2

Tags: java, autocomplete, sublimetext2

I want to have shortcut commands in sublime text 2.

I want to simply type `sopl` and press `tab` to generate `System.out.println('text');` with the word `'text'` selected and ready for me to replace it.

I want to simply type `sop` and press `tab` to generate `System.out.print('text');` with the word `'text'` selected and ready for me to replace it.

I have installed SublimeJava plugin but apparently there is no such short cut

Comment: I don't know about sublime text2 but in Eclipse Syso..Try syso in sublime

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're looking for `pl<tab>` for `System.out.println(|);` and `p<tab>` for `System.out.print(|);`. It doesn't put the `'text'`, but it does put your cursor in the right place to type. Also note that, like Eclipse or IntelliJ, when you expand a Snippet, `Tab` will continue to move you through the positions in the Snippet until you've filled in all the blanks.

These are called "Snippets", and you can find them under `Tools -> Snippets...`. You can add new ones with `Tools -> New Snippet...`.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple, just go to `Tools>Developer>New Snippet..` remove all the code there and copy paste the below code...

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[System.out.println("${1:text}");]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sysout</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.java</scope>
</snippet>
```

now press `ctrl+s` and give some name (make sure that you're saving file with `.sublime-snippet` extension) and click on save.
now open any .java file and type `sysout` and press `tab` that is it...

[you can also refer this article for more info..](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-snippets-in-sublime-text/)